# Восстановление данных

Tags: hdd, восстановление

Ко мне попал жесткий от знакомого, который хочет чтобы я попытался восстановить данные. Данные не критичны, поэтому я взялся за попытку восстановления и попутно захотелось бы разобраться.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: 
Я знаю, что правило хорошего тона требует перед восстановлением, делать копию образа жесткого диска. Сам жесткий диск на один Тб, а у меня нет столько места для записи. Я знаю, что необходимые данные занимают только 20 гигабайт и предполагаю, что раз ОС на этот жесткий не был установлен, то данные будут находиться ближе к центру жесткого диска.

Есть ли возможность, сделать копию диска только первых 50 гигабайт и как это можно сделать?

Спасибо

Comment: Если под Linux, то можно использовать команду dd. Подробнее про неё в интернете найдете, инфы полно.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Посмотрите еще Acronis

Comment: Я бы не был так уверен в расположении данных. Неизвестно, сколько юзался винт, какая там фрагментация. Особенно если юзался под windows

Comment: Думаю вы правы, но всю копию жесткого диска я сделать все равно не смогу. Если не получится, то не страшно, только за ради интереса.